# Qiskit cant run circuit with reset gate with error

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, simulation, transpile

In qiskit if i have a reset gate in a circuit. If i want to add noise to the circuit it wont transpile.

For example:

```
qr= QuantumRegister(2)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr)
qc.reset(qr)
noise_model = NoiseModel()
sim = AerSimulator(method='matrix_product_state', noise_model=noise_model)
transpiled_qc = transpile(qc, sim, optimization_level=0)
res = sim.run(transpiled_qc, shots=10).result()
```

Will fail with the error message:
"HighLevelSynthesis was unable to synthesize Instruction(name='reset', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[])."

But I remove the noise_model:

```
qr= QuantumRegister(2)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr)
qc.reset(qr)
noise_model = NoiseModel()
sim = AerSimulator(method='matrix_product_state')
transpiled_qc = transpile(qc, sim, optimization_level=0)
res = sim.run(transpiled_qc, shots=10).result()
```

It will successfully transpile and run. Is this a qiskit bug or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Interesting. I guess that it has to do with the noise model's basis gates, not building correctly in the absence of errors. I suggest that you open an issue in https://github.com/qiskit/qiskit-aer.

Comment: Done created a bug report: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/issues/2015